# how to enable 'Date Filters' option for date column in excel for pivoted ssas tabular model

Tags: sql, excel, pivot-table, sql-server-data-tools, ssas-tabular

I've got an SSAS tabular model with a column that hold date values. The SQL column is of `date type`. On the SSAS side, the column data type is `Date`.

However, when connecting to the model from Excel, I am unable to see date filter option when I click on date column as which I have mentioned below

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SCo3d.png)

I can see only below options when i click on date column in pivoted table.

- label filter
- value filter

Rows in date column have been considering as text even changed data type and date format as date in ssas model.